# Sinatra - changing a singleton's value between requests

Tags: ruby, sinatra, kissmetrics

I'm using Kissmetrics' [KM gem](http://github.com/kissmetrics/km) for analytics in my Sinatra application. All events are recorded server-side. The problem is that the KM object generated by the gem is a singleton, which means that the ID key, which is supposed to be unique for each user, is preserved across users. That's not good. What I'd like to do is be able to set a new ID for each user. I can either change the source of the KM gem, or use some sort of locking/concurrency mechanism to make sure each event has the proper ID. Both seem too complicated.

Is there any better idea I've overlooked?

Comment: I assume by ID, you mean the unique id set in `KM.init("this is your key"....`) ? Does that mean you are using Kissmetrics to provide metrics on each user separately? I think it is more often used to provided aggregate data for your entire site. Although if you really need it different for each user, and each user has their own KM ID, then you could potentially run `KM.init( user.km_id, ...` or similar  in authentication block, or in a Sinatra `before` block

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. KM claim to enable per person metrics. I thought of using KM.identify per request but then I think I'll run into problems if another user issues requests simultaneously. In this case KM will probably confuse their identities.

Comment: The key is for your app. You establish user identity using `KM.identify('bob@bob.com')` - just call that in a general `before` block, e.g. `before do; KM.identify( current_user.email ) end` - don't worry it won't cross-talk between concurrent requests, they don't share general Ruby objects. It may *persist* though, hence you need to set it early on

Comment: Just tested it. Looks like you're right, there's no cross-talk. Thanks!